# Create App folder and upload file using OneDrive API

Tags: c#, onedrive

i accomplished to connect my App with the OneDrive SDK/API to my OneDrive. 
But how can i create an AppFolder and Upload i.e. a Textfile?

I set up a scope:

```
private readonly string[] scopes = new string[] { "onedrive.readwrite", "wl.offline_access", "wl.signin" };
```

and authenticate the user:

```
((App)Application.Current).OneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(this.scopes);
await ((App)Application.Current).OneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
```

and store the Client in a variable:

```
var myOneDriveClient = ((App)Application.Current).OneDriveClient;
```

Can someone help me with the next steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can get the app folder:

```
var folder = await myOneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();
```

Upload would work like this:

```
var item = await myOneDriveClient
    .Drive
    .Special
    .AppRoot
    .Children["filename"]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .PutAsync<Item>(contentStream);
```